# Windows 8.1 install, lost programs installed on non-C drives

Tags: registry, sql-server-2012, windows-8.1

I had a Windows 8 machine that I recently upgraded to 8.1.  It seems like most of the applications that I had installed to an E drive are now completely or partially forgotten by Windows 8.1-- I've had to reinstall quite a few.

In this case, SQL Server Express 2012 instances no longer show up in my services list and I am unable to connect to them.  Other SQL Server services remain, such as the browsing service.  As far as I can tell, it looks like all of the SQL server components are still in the 'programs and features' section of the control panel, but my media has been deleted from the temp folders so there is no easy way to repair.

**Is there a way to tell Windows 8.1 to refresh the list of installed apps without losing data?**

I do have backups, and I will create a new 8.1 backup prior to testing any suggestions.

My computer has an SSD for the OS, but I've been offloading non-OS apps to a larger 1 TB drive to save space on the SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up downloading the SQL Server 2012 Express installation from microsoft again, which included Service Pack 1.  There was an option to repair instances, and now things seem to be working.

The only error I received when repairing referenced something about not being able to map security logins.  You get an option to 'cancel' or 'retry,' and I just cancelled all of the popups with that error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the whole system without losing data through the "NewUI control pannel"

Here is an article on this topic:
http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2410848,00.asp

Comment: that's not an option.  I'd rather re-install sql server than be forced to reinstall every single app.  It takes 4-5 days to install everything.